# Android back button close popup if opened

Tags: java, android, button, back

I have a main activity , and a popup.xml file that is included in the activity

the problem is when i press the back button , it closes the app directly , whether the popup is opened or not

i got the idea to override the onClick method, add a boolean that will be true when the popup is opened , and false otherwise , then add this condition in the onClick method

i'm still a noob with Android Studio , would anyone please guide me through ?

Thank you.

Comment: Which class is your popup? Dialog? PopupWindow? Post your code where you are creating & showing the popup.

Comment: Show some more codes??

Comment: in my xml file of the main activity 

<include  layout="@layout/activity_popup"
        android:id="@+id/popup"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
         />



in my main activity.java 

private View pop;
pop = findViewById(R.id.popup);

the i use 

pop.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

override the `onBackPressed` in your activity and check if popup is showing. if popup is showing then close popup else do general back press action

```
 @Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if(popupWindow.isShowing())
        popupWindow.dismiss();
    else
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

Comment: Thanks ^^

this solved it 

`@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if(PopUpActive)
        {
            Back(); //the methode that does the things and close popup
        }
        else
        {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }`

ps , my popup is a simple xml file , that is included in my main.xml , then assigned to a View , showing and hiding using

`setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)`

Answer (score 0):

Just override the following method in your `Activity`:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
     //Do whatever you want before the back button should trigger
     super.onBackPressed();  // call this only if you want to close the app
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 @Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if(!(Activity).isFinishing){
//activity is not yet finished
}else{
//activity finishes
super.onBackPressed();
}
}
```